# Working with QEMU on Pintos : make check returns FAIL because QEMU hangs after execution

Tags: operating-system, qemu, pintos

I am working on PINTOS with QEMU setup as the simulator. It works find when I run `pintos run alarm-single`, but the problem occurs when I run the test with `make check`.

The output is produced successfully but the test still returns FAIL because QEMU does not exit successfully with the given command line input. The only way to exit QEMU is to make another command line input `quit`.

Is it possible to add a command line option to completely exit QEMU after the run completes?

Else, is it possible to add a line or two to pintos script or Makefile script so that I can parse `quit` to QEMU after qemu completes `run alarm-single` command?